# Syntax error: Unexpected token equal sign '='

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to build a form on react for a home assignment,
i'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH4pJISKeoI)! 
 tutorial 
 i get this error i couldnt solve nor find a solution

my first attempt:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component{
    state = {
        firstName = "",
        lastName = "",
        email = "",
        phone = "",
    }
```

my second attempt

```
export default class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName = "",
            lastName = "",
            email = "",
            phone = "",
        }
    }
```

they both end up with this error:
Syntax error: Unexpected token
when the arrow points to the equal sign under firstName = ""

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be look like below for both cases.

Use `:` instead of `=` in `this.state` object.

```
this.state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

> [**props**](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

You should use colon for the props for example

```
this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
_resolve = (value) => {}
```

Write:

```
_resolve (value) {}
```

Comment: do you mean _resolve method to interact with state?